# PHP Regex preg_match won't work

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
if (preg_match("/<response>(.*)<\/response>/iUms", '<response>CONNECTED_OK</response>', $mathces))
{
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

I tried this, but at first i had a downloaded page with cURL with the subject I now have hard coded in. I have tried lots of other things but it always return $matches with null.

Comment: You do have a typo, is that just from copying

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match("/<response>(.*)<\/response>/iUms", '<response>CONNECTED_OK</response>', $matches)) { var_dump($matches); }
```

You had  `$mathces` instead of `$matches`

Comment: Damnit, well... I guess I've been coding for too many hours today. Time for bed. But thank you so much!

Comment: @user3788436 No, it has nothing to do with the amount of hours you have been coding. It has to do with you not having error reporting turned on.